# Giving Excel worksheet a Form like look with only fixed number of rows and columns enabled

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to activate only a smaller section of excel sheet and deactivate rest of the sheet, meaning that only say a A4 size is visible and the rest part is grey and nothing happens when you click the grey part.
(EG: Sheet consists of say only 20 rows and 7 colums).

I want to basically, make the sheet appear like a form, where the User can only edit or use certain parts and not the entire sheet.

I have sheen before such type of sheets in presentation, but I don't know how it is done. Can anyone help me with this.?

Comment: As for the second part of your question, this should be posted as a seperate question entierly. How do you know the user won't resize a column to 5 standard columns wide? If you wan't it grey, why can't you just use the background cell colour tool built in to excel? Your questions are a bit to vague for anyone to actually help you here. What **exactly** are you trying to do?

Comment: Well I want to give it a formular look and when the user uses it, I dont want them to be able to put any content, in say column H. Grey makes it more legible that this particular part is off limits. My apologies for not putting this question seperately. I am new to vba as well as stack overflow. So a bit of politeness would be really nice.

Comment: I wasn't being impolite? Perhaps you were reading it that way. Anyhow, you can use the Worksheet Protect Cell feature to the same effect, without VBA, this will stop people being able to select those cells for editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer that doesn't use VBA at Microsoft's support pages:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214081

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate the "background cell colour tool built in excel" that you mentioned.

Comment: I was having a blank moment, the "Fill" tool (the bucket of paint)

Comment: Ok yeah that was a dumb question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally managed giving the sheet a Formular look or in other words, make the appearance of the sheet like a form, without using the Protecting Sheet option.

So say I want the sheet to have 20 rows and upto column G. Its just required to run the following 2-line macro:

```
            Sub Form_Look()
            Rows("21:1048576").RowHeight = 0 'Last Row of a Sheet is 1048576
            Columns("G:XFD").ColumnWidth = 0 'Last Column of a Sheet is XFD
            End Sub
```

And now just run the macro once. Hide it , delete it, whatever, But now the sheet will permanently on saving, look like you designed. :)